# Format on how I will prepare an article in latex on my biography

Tags: biblatex

I want to know how I will prepare an article in latex on my biography

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your question is a bit generic, pleas look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner and then try to create a minimal example and give some details about your problem.

Comment: Also this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/101651 could be useful

Comment: You can see also this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214618/author-biographies-in-elsarticle

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in your question, please? Are you looking for a beginner's guide to `biblatex`? (In that case https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/ would be a good place to start.) Or are you looking for an introduction into LaTeX in general? (Then you may want to start with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11.)